# Configuring Gquery in gwt in netbeans

Tags: xml, gwt, netbeans, gquery

I am trying to create a GWT application which uses GQuery in Netbeans.I have referred to 
http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted

But when I am importing the package of GQuery in my Entrpoint.java file and trying to build it is giving me error:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/GWT/gquery/lib/gwtquery-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/google/gwt/query/client/SelectorEngine.java'
[ERROR] Line 94:  Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.query.client.impl.SelectorEngineImpl' cannot be abstract
[ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors 

ProjectPath\nbproject\build-gwt.xml:262: The following error occurred while executing this line:
ProjectPath\nbproject\build-gwt.xml:411:
```

I am inheriting the module in main-gwt.xml file  and also setting the class path of my GQuery jar file.I am unable to use the packages.

Answer (score 0):

You are still using a snapshot release.

Try to use the [last stable release](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Downloads?tm=2) corresponding to your GWT version !

Comment: Thanks jdramaix: Got the solution the jar file I was using was not correct used new jar file GWT Query and got the solution.Can you tell me how to access a widget library control like label or Textbox in GQuery,I am able to modify the html control but not able to access widget controls.